# How to re-render <p:panel> from <p:selectOneRadio> option when form fails a validation?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

Render works fine during initial load of the page, but once the form has been submitted and some component failed a validation re-render does not trigger, the panel does not show and hide anymore and page must be refreshed again. I'm still new with jsf.

Sample Code

```
    <p:selectOneRadio id="accommodationOptions" value="#{travelRequestMBean.accommodationOptions}">  
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{field['accord3Radio2']}" itemValue="2" />  
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{field['accord3Radio1']}" itemValue="1" />
                        <f:ajax render="panelMoreAccommodation2"/> 
    </p:selectOneRadio>

    <p:panel id="panelMoreAccommodation2" widgetVar="panelMoreAccommodation2" 
            visible="#{travelRequestMBean.accommodationOptions == 1}" closable="true" toggleable="true">
                    <p:graphicImage url="/images/hotel-noun_project_4398.svg" alt="#{field['accord3Label2']}" height="24px" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{field['accord3Label2']}" />
    </p:panel>
```

Also I have tried the other variant of this using a boolean attribute in the backing bean with an ajax event on the selectoneradio, result was still the same and panel does not do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally having some tweaks, the problem was this attribute on the target panel

```
closable="true"
```

After removing this attribute the ajax update worked again even after a submit with a failed validation.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you validate your inputs. But take a look at http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/csv/basic.xhtml with the combination of

```
update=":panelMoreAccommodation2"
```

And instead of visible use render.

Comment: I didn't include the validation it is just a simple field with a required="true", also the update was my first approach using this inside the <p:selectOneRadio> `<p:ajax event="click" listener="#{travelRequestMBean.accommodationFlag()}" 
               update=":#{p:component('panelMoreAccommodation2')}">
               </p:ajax>`

Comment: And this doesn't worked? With the "update"? I think you have to add an event to you f:ajax event="..." but i don't know which one. Or try to surround the selectOneRadio Element with the ajax <f:ajax>..</f:ajax> And try p:ajax http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/listener.xhtml

Comment: This properly works. My problem is after the form is submitted with failed validations then it will stop working.

Comment: Okay i have to learn to read ... :D It's not clear to me, did u tried something like this <p:ajax update="panelMoreAccommodation2, accommodationOptions"/>